# How to redirect to root if the query param is not defined?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

I wanna to redirect my website to the home `/` if the is no query param is defined. I am building a search website with nextjs is which `/` is the home and `/search` is the search page. I am passing the query term in the URL as `/search?query=myterm`. when a user tries to access the `/search` without the `query` I wanna to redirect the user the home `/`. But how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of the redirects mechanism: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects

You can read the value of query params like this:

```
module.exports = {
  async redirects() {
      {
        source: '/specific/:path*',
        has: [
          {
            type: 'query',
            key: 'page',
            value: 'home',
          }
        ],
        permanent: false,
        destination: '/:path*/:page',
      },
  }
}
```